# Why is my function overwriting global variable values that are passed to it?

Tags: python, function, scope, global-variables, local-variables

My understanding of variable scope in Python was that if you pass a global variable into a function, the global variable's value will not be changed by any operations done on it within the scope of the function. For example, if I had a function:

```
def add_two_to(num):
   num += 2
   return num
```

and I ran:

```
my_number = 5
new_number = add_two_to(my_number)
```

I would expect the value of `new_number` to be 7, and the value of `my_number` to remain 5. When I run this code in a Jupyter notebook, that is exactly what happens.

But for some reason, when I run the following code:

```
def place_on_board(board):
    board[1] = 'X'
    return board
    
game_board = [0,1,2]
new_board = place_on_board(game_board)
```

*Both* `new_board` *and* `game_board` now have the value `[0,'X',2]`. This is happening regardless of where I declare `game_board`. Why is my `place_on_board` function overwriting the global variable `game_board`? It seems to go against everything I thought I understood about variable scope.

Comment: when you pass a mutable object (like a list) to a function, the function receives a reference to the original object, not a copy of it. This means that any modifications made to the object inside the function will affect the original object outside the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)